# Media queries in my web page not working in firefox and IE and Edge browsers

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to place an image over (on top of) previous div,previous div's position is relative and this img tag has position absolute, for that I wrote media queries for all devices to position the image correctly on different sizes.
Now my problem is media queries are not working for IE,Edge browser and Mozilla Firefox.
my image is totally getting disappeared in these browsers.
my code:

```
<div class="temp">
</div>

    <img src="" class="img img-responsive tit">
```

and my css is

```
    .temp{
        padding-top: 4rem;
        background-image: url('../img/BG.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        width:100%;
        height: 45rem;
        position: relative;
        opacity: 0.7;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    @media only screen
    and (min-device-width : 320px)
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {

    .temp{
        height: 30rem;
    }
    .tit{
        content: url("../img/Title_Landscape.png");
        position: absolute;
        top: 10rem;
        width: 100%;
    }

}
    @media only screen
    and (min-device-width : 768px)
    and (max-device-width : 1024px) {

    .tit{
        content: url("../img/Title_Landscape.png");
        position: absolute;
        top: 8rem;
        width: 100%;
    }   
    .temp{
        height: 40rem;
    }
}
    @media only screen
    and (min-width : 1224px){
        .tit{
        content: url("../img/Title_Landscape.png");
        position: absolute;
        top: -1rem;
        width: 100%;
    }       
    }
```

Comment: have you tried to reset your browser's cache???

Answer (score 0):

A few potential issues:

1. **`img src` missing**. Move the `img` url from CSS `content:` to the actual HTML `img` per the standard syntax. `content:` property is reserved to `::after` and `::before` pseudo-elements. See [this MDN entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) for reference.
2. **`device-width` vs `width`**: You might want to use `width` for media queries, especially when you're testing on your desktop devices. See [this SitePoint article](https://www.sitepoint.com/media-queries-width-vs-device-width/) for reference.
3. **Missing width ranges**: Your media queries handle `320px-480px`, `768px-1024px`, and `>1224px` ranges, and skipping all other possible pixel dimensions. When viewport size falls within those ranges, browsers won't have styling to choose from. You might want to either

   - Apply global styling outside media queries,
   - Provide all potential ranges, or
   - Use only `min-` or `max-` widths, so there's no missing ranges.

Not knowing what your intention is, and how the entire page is configured, I cannot provide further pointers. See https://codepen.io/baadaa/pen/RwNdpvo for quick look.